# Highlight Event

Tags: objective-c, xcode, events, uiimageview, highlight

I'm using an UIImageView as a button with two different images on it, one normal, and another one when the image is clicked (highlighted). I've managed to create a Tap Gesture Recognizer and link it to the image so that when I click,  highlights it and change the image, but how can I change it back to the first image when stop clicking? Should I use Long Press Gesture Recognizer?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you just want it to highlight momentarily when you tap on it?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be highlighted only when I'm still pressing it, if I release, it stop highlighting it, I can also do this with the UIButton right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UIButton, set its style to custom and set regular UIImages as normal/highlighted states directly from Interface Builder or programatically. There is no need to do overhead that way.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could highlight the button with another image.
It worked now

Thanks again! :)